# how to restart forever processes with the same log

Tags: node.js, forever

`forever restartall` seems to restart my processes but not with the same logfile / errorfile that I defined when I called:

```
forever -o out.log -e err.log my-script.js
```

Is there a way to use restartall while using the same logs?

Comment: forever restartall works fine for me. witht the same file. you could also restart using the pid

Comment: I am thinking about using logging service as Winston and plug it in by editing forever logging functionality. Looks bad, but if forever gives you some logging methods, then the plugin process would be clean as it should be.